# Wordpress Wp_query with custom field display nothing

Tags: wordpress

I have problem with my `WP_Query` who display nothing.
I'm trying to set up a custom query that returns only one custom post type choose by the value of a custom field.

I use ACF for the custom field.

Here is the code I have:

```
<section class="ui  very relaxed list custom">
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <article>
        <header class="page-header expo">
            Some content with custom field
        </header>
        <section class="content">
            <?php
            $artiste_name = get_field('relation_artiste');
            /*$name = $artiste['post_name'];
            // vars
            $field_name = "relation_artiste";
            $field = get_field_object($field_name);

            echo $field['post_name'] . ': ' . $field['value'];
            */

            //$field_name = "relation_artiste";
            $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'Artiste',
            'meta_key' => 'relation_artiste',
            'meta_value' => $artiste_name
            );
            // query
            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
            ?>
            <?php //echo $artiste_name ?>
            <?php  if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
                <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <aside class="item">
                        <section class="ui small images">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('portrait', array('class'=>"home img-size")); ?>
                        </section>
                        <p class="item-description">
                            <?php the_excerpt(2); ?>
                        </p>
                        <footer class="item-foot">
                            <a class="nextlink right floated content" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Voir l'artiste <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></a>
                        </footer>
                    </aside><!-- Aside info -->
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

                <?php the_content(); ?>

            </section>
        </article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use WP META Query for this please check below link

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Thank for your answer Himanshu, but i don't really understand.. I juste need to change `$the_query = new WP_Query($args);` by `$the_query = new WP_Meta_Query($args);` ?

Comment: $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'Artiste',
           'meta_query' => array(
            'meta_key' => 'relation_artiste',
            'meta_value' => $artiste_name
           )
         );
         // query
         $the_query = new WP_Query($args);. I do this but now he show me all my custom post 'Artiste' and not one i selected with my custom field